# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'newspaper3k'

Tags: python, python-newspaper

I'm attempting to install the newspaper module on python, but I keep getting an error saying that there is no such module.

I've tried making sure my directory is set to the right place, and I've checked that the module is installed. PyCharm, which I'm using, shows it to be installed when I check there. Why is it saying that there is no module when I've clearly already installed it?

```
Alexs-MacBook-Pro:~ alexfrandsen14$ pip3 install newspaper3k
Requirement already satisfied: newspaper3k in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages (0.2.8)
Requirement already satisfied: jieba3k>=0.35.1 in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from newspaper3k) (0.35.1)
Requirement already satisfied: lxml>=3.6.0 in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from newspaper3k) (4.3.0)
Requirement already satisfied: python-dateutil>=2.5.3 in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from newspaper3k) (2.7.5)
Requirement already satisfied: requests>=2.10.0 in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/requests-2.18.1-py3.7.egg (from newspaper3k) (2.18.1)
Requirement already satisfied: Pillow>=3.3.0 in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from newspaper3k) (5.4.1)
Requirement already satisfied: feedfinder2>=0.0.4 in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from newspaper3k) (0.0.4)
Requirement already satisfied: cssselect>=0.9.2 in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from newspaper3k) (1.0.3)
Requirement already satisfied: beautifulsoup4>=4.4.1 in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/beautifulsoup4-4.6.0-py3.7.egg (from newspaper3k) (4.6.0)
Requirement already satisfied: feedparser>=5.2.1 in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from newspaper3k) (5.2.1)
Requirement already satisfied: tldextract>=2.0.1 in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from newspaper3k) (2.2.0)
Requirement already satisfied: PyYAML>=3.11 in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from newspaper3k) (3.13)
Requirement already satisfied: tinysegmenter==0.3 in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from newspaper3k) (0.3)
Requirement already satisfied: nltk>=3.2.1 in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from newspaper3k) (3.4)
Requirement already satisfied: six>=1.5 in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from python-dateutil>=2.5.3->newspaper3k) (1.12.0)
Requirement already satisfied: certifi>=2017.4.17 in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/certifi-2018.10.15-py3.7.egg (from requests>=2.10.0->newspaper3k) (2018.10.15)
Requirement already satisfied: chardet<3.1.0,>=3.0.2 in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/chardet-3.0.4-py3.7.egg (from requests>=2.10.0->newspaper3k) (3.0.4)
Requirement already satisfied: idna<2.6,>=2.5 in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/idna-2.5-py3.7.egg (from requests>=2.10.0->newspaper3k) (2.5)
Requirement already satisfied: urllib3<1.22,>=1.21.1 in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3-1.21.1-py3.7.egg (from requests>=2.10.0->newspaper3k) (1.21.1)
Requirement already satisfied: setuptools in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from tldextract>=2.0.1->newspaper3k) (39.0.1)
Requirement already satisfied: requests-file>=1.4 in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from tldextract>=2.0.1->newspaper3k) (1.4.3)
Requirement already satisfied: singledispatch in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from nltk>=3.2.1->newspaper3k) (3.4.0.3)
Alexs-MacBook-Pro:~ alexfrandsen14$ python3
Python 3.7.1 (v3.7.1:260ec2c36a, Oct 20 2018, 03:13:28) 
[Clang 6.0 (clang-600.0.57)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import newspaper3k 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'newspaper3k'
>>>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's importable as just [`newspaper`](https://pypi.org/project/newspaper3k/):

```
import newspaper
```

(The PyPI name will not always align with the package name.)

```
>>> import newspaper
>>> newspaper.__version__
'0.2.7'
```

From shell:

```
$ pip list | grep newspaper
newspaper3k              0.2.7
```

To be more specific, the name `newspaper3k` is defined in `setup.py`.  This does not necessarily have to match the top-level package name at the file level.